# How to Return to activity after the notification has appeared? Notification is not clickable

Tags: java, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I have problem - it is not possible to return to the main activity after clicking on the received notification. The notification itself is not clickable. The notification is triggered in the onPause method (in the background)

My main activity is MainActivity, which is setting up notification via PendingIntent and AlarmManager

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private NotificationManager notificationManager;

private static final int NOTIFY_ID = 1;

private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "CHANNEL_ID";

NotificationPublisher notificationPublisher;

Button b1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    createNotificationChannel();
}

private void createNotificationChannel() {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = "LemubitReminderChannel";
        String description = "Channel for Lemubit Reminder";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("notifyLemubid", name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);

        
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

}

private void reminderMethod (){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Напоминание о запуске фонового уведомления", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationPublisher.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    long inPauseTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long ten = 2 * 1000;
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, inPauseTime + ten, pendingIntent);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    reminderMethod();
}
}
```

Broadcast receiver

```
public class NotificationPublisher extends BroadcastReceiver {

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    int unicode = 0x1F62D;



    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "notifyLemubid")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle("текст " + getEmojiByUnicode(unicode))
            .setContentText("текст")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
    notificationManagerCompat.notify(200, builder.build());

}

public String getEmojiByUnicode(int unicode){
    return new String(Character.toChars(unicode));
}
}
```

Comment: Does the `BroadcastReceiver` get triggered? Does the `Notification` get shown?

Comment: Since your `Intent` is for a `BroadcastReceiver`, you should remove the flags `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` or `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`. These flags are used if you have an `Intent` for an `Activity`.

Comment: i removed them, but it did not help. Is it possible to return to activity using getBroadcast?

Comment: Answer my questions please. Does the `BroadcastReceiver` get triggered (does `onReceive()` get called)? Does the `Notification` get shown?

Comment: i think yes, Notification will be show

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `contentIntent` on the `Notification`, then, when the user clicks the `Notification`, the `contentIntent` will be dispatched. If you want the user to open an `Activity` of your app, then just create an `Intent` to your `Activity`, wrap that in a `PendingIntent` and call `setContentIntent()` on the `Notification. There's hundreds of howtos and tutorials for how to do this, just search a bit.